# Customize Sql select

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
    ID     |      NAME     | INDICATOR |
    -----------------------------------
    0001          Item1       Y
    -----------------------------------
    0001          Item2       N
    -----------------------------------
    0006          Item3       N
    -----------------------------------
    0004          Item4       N
    -----------------------------------
    0004          Item5       N
```

Table 2

```
    ID         INDICATOR 
    --------------------
    0001          Y
    ---------------------
    0002          Y
    ---------------------
    0003          Y
    ---------------------
    0004          Y
    ---------------------
    0005          N
```

First I need to select the ids whose indicator is Y in table 2, then with that selection i have to select the name and id whose indicator is N in table 2,

criteria :

if the ids of table2 is not present in table1, then my selection should return a value for name as NOTDEFINED and for Id which don't have Y in table1.

**OUTPUT HAS TO BE**

```
    ID     |      NAME     
    -----------------------
    0001          Item1     
    ------------------------
    0002        NOTDEFINED  
    ------------------------
    0003        NOTDEFINED  
    ------------------------
    0004        NOTDEFINED
```

Is it possible to write a select query like this, if so kindly help.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you need would be different depending on backend you are using. For example with MS SQL server:

```
select a.id,  
   case when Indicator = 'N' then 'NOTDEFINED' else a.name end as Name
from tableA a 
where exists (select * from tableB b where a.ID = b.ID and b.Indicator = 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t2.ID ID, IF(t1.name <> NULL, t1.name, 'NOTDEFINED') NAME FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON (t2.ID = t1.id AND t1.INDICATOR = 'Y') GROUP BY t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to say you want the name whose indicator is *Y in table 1* then use example 1, otherwise, example 2 should return what you asked.

```
--Example 1    
select table2.ID, isnull(table1.Name,'NOTDEFINED') from table2
inner join table1 on table2.ID = table1.ID
where table2.Indicator = 'Y' and table1.Indicator = 'N'

--Example 2
select table2.ID, isnull(table1.Name,'NOTDEFINED') from table2
inner join table1 on table2.ID = table1.ID
where table2.Indicator = 'Y' and table1.Indicator = 'Y'
```